# HTML Image tag doesn’t render table properly assigned to title attribute

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to assign table to image's title property using javascript but when I hover over the image it doesn't render a table instead it displays the table as text.

```
function FormatAssessorInfo(P1, P2)
{           
    var ToolTipTable = "<table width='200px' border='0' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='2'> <tbody> <tr> <td> Phone: </td> <td> " + P1 + " </td> <td> Cell: </td> <td> " + P2 + " </td> </tr> </tbody> </table>";
    return '<img src="/files/404048/93171/Info-32.png" height="15" width="15" title="' + ToolTipTable + '" style=""/>'; 
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with what you're trying. You may want to use some `tooltip` plugin for that. Like [`jQuery tooltips`](http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/).

Answer (score 0):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/title):

> The title attribute contains **text** representing advisory information,
>   related to the element it belongs to.

Since it's text, and not html, it not gets interpreted by the browser.